# use elements in a list for dataframe names

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a list like this:

```
network = ['facebook','organic',instagram']
```

And I create 3 dataframes: facebook_count, organic_count, instagram_count that each  type of network.

```
facebook_count = df[df.isin(['facebook installs'])]
organic_count = df[df.isin(['organic installs'])]
instagram_count = df[df.isin(['instagram installs'])]
```

so is there a way that write a iteration that create these 3 dataframes at once?
I write something like this:

```
for i in range(len(network)+1):
    network[i]+'_count' = df[df.isin([network[i]+' installs'])]
```

But it returns a SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient solution would be to create a dictionary storing the dataframes:

```
d = {i + '_count': df[df.isin([i + ' installs'])] for i in network}
```

And to get a dataframe, do:

```
print(d['facebook_count'])
```

Output will be the `facebook_count` dataframe with expected values

Comment: I posted right after you. Your answer is indeed more elegant and I learned new thing that you may use something like a list comprehension in setting up dictionary. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix is to use `dictionary`

```
count = {}    # creating a new dictionary
for i in range(len(network)+1):
    count[network[i]+'_count'] = df[df.isin([network[i]+' installs'])]
```

This way, you are using the name `facebook_count`,`organic_count` and `instagram_count` as keys of the dictionary

i.e. `count['facebook_count'] = df[df.isin('facebook installs'])]`